# Storing or maintaining ListView EditText values into ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-edittext

My question is :- **I want to store all EditText values of ListView into ArrayList**.

In my App I have `Custom ListView` with row as `EditText`. Just consider `listview` have 20 rows.
 when i m doing this task I **Firstly** faced Scrolling Issue of `ListView`(that means values of `EditText` are messed.(places somewhere else)), But Luckly solved it.
Now I want to store that all values into `ArrayList<String>`.
 Yes I also written code for that into my adapter.But **Getting Exception NullPointer** when setting that list to outside use.
Also I never want to set that ArrayList inside getView(causes problem when view recycling)
 I known that Exception becoz of `TextWatcher Listener`. then what should be alternative for that.Also I never have any button for saving data.Just want to store as values appears into EditText's of ListView one by one.
Here is my Adapter Class :-

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;       
     public ArrayList<String> _values;
     ArrayList<String> data;
     Model model;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,int res,ArrayList<String> obj) {
        super(context,res,obj);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);             
        _values=new ArrayList<String>();
        model=new Model();
        this.data=obj;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();               
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);              
           holder.tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           holder.tv.setText(data.get(position));
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.tv.setText(data.get(position));
        }

        holder.caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt) 
            {
                _values.add(edt.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.ref=position;
        holder.caption.setText(_values.get(position));
        model.setData(_values);//here getting exception
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    EditText caption;   
    TextView tv;
    int ref;
}
```

This is Model Class I m using for Outside Purpose about that String

```
 public class Model 
 {
   ArrayList<String> data;

   public ArrayList<String> getData() {
       return data;
   }
   public void setData(ArrayList<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
    for(String str : data)
        Log.v("data=", str);
   }
}
```

Comment: use arrayList instead of array. may b helpful

Comment: ok as per ur suggestion i have updated my code..Lets see adapter class.. getting IndexoutOfbound Exp. at  holder.caption.setText(_values.get(position)); line

Comment: please let me see your public int getCount() method of the ArrayAdapter class? what are your returning from this? paste the code of getCount() method

Comment: i never used getCount() method yet...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may this help you

```
Arrays.sort(data);
```

and than

```
MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(<args>) 
ma.notifydatasetchanged();
<ListViewInstance>.setAdapter(ma);
```